# R: Replacing values in a column with corresponding values

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

How do you replace values in a column when the value fulfils certain conditions in R?

Here I have two data frames.

```
Fruits <- c("Apple", "Grape Fruits", "Lemon", "Peach", "Banana", "Orange", "Strawberry", "Apple")
df1 <- data.frame(Fruits)

df1
   Fruits
   Apple                
   Grape Fruits             
   Lemon                
   Peach                
   Banana               
   Orange               
   Strawberry               
   Apple



Name <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Lemon", "Grape", "Peach","Pinapple")
Rename <- c("Manzana", "Naranja", "Limon", "Uva", "Melocoton", "Anana")
df2 <- data.frame(Name, Rename)

df2
   Name       Rename
   Apple       Manzana          
   Orange      Naranja          
   Lemon       Limon            
   Grape       Uva          
   Peach       Melocoton            
   Pinapple    Anana
```

I want to replace the values in `df1$Fruits` to corresponding values in `df2$Rename`, only when each value in `df1$Fruits` matches that in `df2$Name`.

So the designated data frame would be like this.

```
  Fruits
  Manzana                
  Grape Fruits             
  Limon                
  Melocoton                
  Banana               
  Naranja               
  Strawberry               
  Manzana
```

Does anybody know how to do this? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: have you try merge ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using plyr

```
library(plyr)
new.fruits <- mapvalues(Fruits, from = Name, to = Rename)
df <- data.frame(Fruits=new.fruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` and then replace all NA by their respective fruits.

```
df3 <- merge(df1,df2, by.x = "Fruits", by.y = "Name", all.x = T)
df3$Rename[is.na(df3$Rename)] <- df3$Fruits[is.na(df3$Rename)]
```

If you need to keep the order:

```
df1$id  <- 1:nrow(df1)
df3 <- merge(df1,df2, by.x = "Fruits", by.y = "Name", all.x = T)
df3$Rename[is.na(df3$Rename)] <- df3$Fruits[is.na(df3$Rename)]
df3 <- df3[order(df3$id),]
data.frame(Fruits = df3[,"Rename"])
#        Fruits
# 1      Manzana
# 2 Grape Fruits
# 3        Limon
# 4    Melocoton
# 5       Banana
# 6      Naranja
# 7   Strawberry
# 8      Manzana
```

Shorter `match` solution from @Wen below

```
df1$new=df2$Rename[match(df1$Fruits,df2$Name)]
df1$new[is.na(df1$new)] <- df1$Fruits[is.na(df1$new)]
```

Comment: this will change the order of df1

Comment: Using match instead merge `df1$new=df2$Rename[match(df1$Fruits,df2$Name)]`

Comment: yes it will change the order but we can get around that if needed. added additional section to keep order

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` with `pmatch` can be provide desired output.

```
df1$Fruits <- apply(df1,1,function(x){
  matched = (df2$Name == x)
  if(any(matched)){
    as.character(df2$Rename[matched])
  } else {
    x
  }})

df1
#         Fruits
# 1      Manzana
# 2 Grape Fruits
# 3        Limon
# 4    Melocoton
# 5       Banana
# 6      Naranja
# 7   Strawberry
# 8      Manzana
```

Comment: thank you, but i don't want a partial match, I want the values to be replaced only when it exactly matches.

Comment: @GabrielMacotti Then dont use `pmatch`. Just use `==` operator. I have updated answer.